# Two dimensional recurrence relation $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)\cdot(n-1) + f(n-1,k-1)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm struggling to get the following recurrence relation into a closed form if possible:

$$f(n,n)=1$$
$$f(n,1)=(n-1)!$$
$$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)\cdot(n-1) + f(n-1,k-1)$$

where $f$, $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, and $k\leq n$. I've tried to plug the formulas to look for patterns, but I'm not doing very well... And, is there any software that can handle this kind of problem?

Edit: Removed redundant part of definition.

Comment: I think your k is $k < n$ or else you are in the $f(n, n)$ case.

Comment: Why have you written $f(2, 1)$ and $f(2, 2)$ separately? They are just special cases of $f(n, 1)$ and $f(n, n)$.

Comment: Ah! You have a point there. Yes, that is a redundant definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, Mastrem, for valuable input.

It turns out that $f(n,k)={n\brack k}$, in other words (unsigned) Stirling numbers of the first kind.

I found [this](http://oeis.org/A094638) by searching the OEIS.

Edit: Fixed typo (from "signed" to "unsigned"), added the following:

Proof: From the Wikipedia-article [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) we have a recurrence relation for these numbers:

$${{n+1}\brack k}=n{n\brack k}+{n\brack{k-1}}$$

With the substitution $n\rightarrow n-1$ we get

$${n\brack k}=(n-1){{n-1}\brack k}+{{n-1}\brack{k-1}}$$

which is exactly in the same form as

$$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)\cdot(n-1)+f(n-1,k-1)$$

Looking at starting-values we also see that the initial conditions must be equivalent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/603554)

Comment: @user37238:  The OP is reporting an answer they discovered, with a fairly clear indication of sources.  While other Answers may supply more detail, I think this is a valuable post that should not be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for improving the typography, Professor Scott!

Answer (score 1):

Say $k=n-1$. According to the third part of your definition:
$$f(n,n-1)=f(n-1,n-1)\cdot (n-1) + f(n-1,n-2)=f(n-1,n-2)+n-1$$
Let $A_n$ be $f(n, n-1)$. Now we have:
$$A_n = A_{n-1}+n-1$$
We have $A_2=1$ and thus:
$$A_n = \dfrac{(n-2)^2+n-2}{2}-n+4$$
So:
$$f(n,n-1)=\dfrac{(n-2)^2+n-2}{2}-n+4$$

Say $k=n-2$. Now:
$$f(n,n-2)=f(n-1,n-2)\cdot (n-1) + f(n-1, k-3)$$
using our definition of $A_n$:
$$f(n,n-2)=A_{n-1}(n-1)+f(n-1, n-3)=\bigg(\dfrac{(n-2)^2+n-2}{2}-n+4\bigg)(n-1)+f(n-1,n-3)$$
Now define $B_n = f(n,n-2)$:
$$B_n=\bigg(\dfrac{(n-2)^2+n-2}{2}-n+4\bigg)(n-1)+B_{n-1}$$

When you want to find $f(a,b)$, simply find the formula belonging to $f(n,n-(a-b))$ and use the fact that $f(n,1)=(n-1)!$